# List Windows process memory handle

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, process, handle

I would like to list all the memory blocks allocated within my own process. (GlobalAlloc, HeapAlloc, CoMemAlloc)
Memory address, size.

Possible?

Comment: `RtlEnumProcessHeaps` + `HeapWalk` if for heaps. `VirtualQuery` for all alocated memory

Comment: You could try to use [GetProcessMemoryInfo function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo)to retrieve information about the memory usage of the specified process. And you could refer to the Doc:[Memory Management Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-management-functions)